# How to use eventClick when dynamically adding events to fullCalendar?

Tags: node.js, fullcalendar, ejs

I have created an object called `myEvent` and use it to render events dynamically to `fullCalendar`. My question is how do I apply `eventClick` in this situation, I've tried many different ways and done a ton of research but there doesn't seem to be any information on this.

My current code looks like so...

```
var myCalendar = $('#calendar'); 
myCalendar.fullCalendar();       
<% for(var i = 0; i < group.meetings.length; i++) { %>
  var startDay = '<%= group.meetings[i].startDay%>'.split("/");
  console.log(startDay[0]);
  var startTime = '<%= group.meetings[i].startTime%>';
  var endDay = '<%= group.meetings[i].endDay%>'.split("/");
  var endTime = '<%= group.meetings[i].endTime%>';
  var startDayFormatted = moment(startDay[2] + "-" + startDay[0] + "-" + startDay[1] + "T" + startTime).toDate().toISOString();
  var endedDayFormatted = moment(endDay[2] + "-" + endDay[0] + "-" + endDay[1] + "T" + endTime).toDate().toISOString();
  console.log(startDay[0]);
  var myEvent = {
    title: '<%= group.meetings[i].meetingName%>',
    allDay: true,
    start: startDayFormatted,
    end: endedDayFormatted,
    // Need if statement here after we add the completed boolean
    <% if(group.meetings[i].final == true) {%>
    color: 'blue',
    textColor: 'white'
    <%} else if(group.meetings[i].final == false) {%>
    color: 'yellow',
    textColor: 'black'
    <%}%>
  };
  myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent, true);
<%}%>
```

Comment: At present you are not able to add any events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up figuring out my problem. I just has to make the the `for` loop into a function and return the object `myEvent`. After I would just call `fullCalendar` like so

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [getEvents()],
  eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    // whatever you want it to do.
  }
});
```